# Filter JSON list based on an element appearing in a member's list using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm using `jq` to try to filter a JSON list based on the content of a list inside the objects within that list. Here's a sample of my JSON document:

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "path": [
        "root"
      ],
      "outputs": {
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d"
      }
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "other1"
      ],
      "outputs": {
        "e": "f",
        "g": "h"
      }
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "other2"
      ],
      "outputs": {
        "i": "j",
        "k": "l"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the `modules` list to the object where the `path` list contains "root", then return the `outputs` object. Essentially I want to return:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

which I can do using `jq .modules[0].outputs` (see [example on http://jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/8AR39JSUN3)) but I don't want to make an assumption that the object I'm interested in is the 0th element of the `modules` list, instead I want to filter the `modules` list where the `path` list contains an element "root".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Typical, as soon as I post the question I stumble upon the answer through trial and error.

`.modules[] | select(.path == ["root"]).outputs`

see [example on jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/U1ld6BOcg8)

[image]